# Creating search query in MSACCESS

Tags: ms-access, search, ms-access-2007

I created three table in MSAccess (PCH Info, Attorney zip-county, Medical-zip code-county). Each table have similar field of zip code, city and county. My Goal is to search for either of the zip code, city and county in the 3 table and return result meeting either one or 2 of the search criteria.
I ve already created 3 search field and build my query using UNION on the three table. But my problem is if I search specifically for a data it returns the results with other results which doesnt meet the criteria. See code below

```
    SELECT [PCH Info].City, [PCH Info].[Zip Code], [PCH Info].County, "PCH Info"
FROM [PCH Info]
WHERE (([PCH Info].City) Like Forms!Search.qcity & "*") And (([PCH Info].[Zip Code]) Like Forms!Search.qcode & "*") And (([PCH Info].County) Like Forms!Search.qcounty & "*") OR (([PCH Info].[Network Member]) = Yes)

 UNION

SELECT [Medical-Zip Code-County].City, [Medical-Zip Code-County].[ZIP Code], [Medical-Zip Code-County].County , "Medical-Zip Code-County"
FROM [Medical-Zip Code-County]
WHERE (([Medical-Zip Code-County].City) Like Forms!Search.qcity & "*") And (([Medical-Zip Code-County].[ZIP Code]) Like Forms!Search.qcode & "*") And (([Medical-Zip Code-County].County) Like Forms!Search.qcounty & "*")

 UNION 

SELECT [Attorney-Zip-County].City, [Attorney-Zip-County].[ZIP Code], [Attorney-Zip-County].[Country/Region], "Attorney-Zip-County"
FROM  [Attorney-Zip-County]
WHERE (([Attorney-Zip-County].City) Like Forms!Search.qcity & "*") And (([Attorney-Zip-County].[ZIP Code]) Like Forms!Search.qcode & "*") And (([Attorney-Zip-County].[Country/Region]) Like Forms!Search.qcounty & "*");
```

My major challenge comes from the first query where PCH Info.Network Member = Yes, if i do a search to meet this criteria, it still give me results which does meet the criteria. What could I be doing wrong or is the UNION query the problem? thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `AND [PCH Info.Network Member] = Yes`?  With an `OR` all the other criteria will be ignored the moment Network Member = Yes is true.

Comment: @mellamokb when I tried AND [PCH Info.Network Member] = Yes, no result was result

Comment: If you're asking if the UNION is the problem, why don't you try the first query without it? Are you actually passing values from your form fields or is everything Like * ?

Comment: @JeffO, values passed is LIKE *, this allow search for possible value data in the database.  Yeah the first query works without the UNION but as soon as the other query comes in, everything changes

Comment: Are you sure these three tables shouldn't be a single table? Any time I have three tables with the same fields, the flag goes up in my mind that I'm dealing with three subtypes of a single entity, and they belong in a single table. The fact that you have to UNION them back together into a single SQL SELECT suggests that this is actually the case.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT City, [ZIP Code], County, Source, [Network Member] 
FROM (
   SELECT p.City, p.[Zip Code], p.County, 
          "PCH Info" As Source, p.[Network Member]
   FROM [PCH Info] p

   UNION ALL

   SELECT m.City, m.[ZIP Code], m.County , 
          "Medical-Zip Code-County" As Source, False As [Network Member]
   FROM [Medical-Zip Code-County] m

   UNION ALL

   SELECT a.City, a.[ZIP Code], a.[Country/Region], 
          "Attorney-Zip-County" As Source, False As [Network Member]
   FROM  [Attorney-Zip-County] a) As r

WHERE (r.City Like Forms!Search!qcity & "*"
       And r.[Zip Code] Like Forms!Search!qcode & "*"
       And r.County Like Forms!Search!qcounty & "*") 
OR r.[Network Member] = Yes
```